# Google Analytics on WikiMedia Page

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, mediawiki

I would like to know how to add my wiki page to a google analytics tracking. I have tried different approaches, using the tag manager or trying to add the necessary codes over  and , but I am really really new to this.

Can anyone help me with that?

Thank you

Comment: Do you mean setting up Google Analytics on your own **MediaWiki** installation?

Comment: So, as I said, I am really new at all this. What I have is: I have a wikimedi page that I can, for example, login and edit the page as I want. But I wanted to check the traffic over the page and apparently it is possible to do that with Google Analytics. However, to get it working, you have to apparently "tag" your page with some code, which I cannot do. I have installed Ampps in my computer, which has the mediawiki inside it (not sure if this is of any help)
Thanks for the help!

Comment: So this is your OWN installation of MediaWiki (NOT Wikimedia) installation, correct?

Comment: Exactly, I have my own MediaWiki installation. Sorry for the mistake (not Wikimedia)